# Android Studio git across platforms

Tags: android, linux, windows, git, android-studio

I have 3 computers currently, Desktop, Laptop and Tablet. The two first ones is running Linux, but the tablet is a newer Intel BayTrail with no Linux support at the moment, so I am running Windows 10 on it for now.

All 3 devices is setup with my development environment auto synced using Dropbox. Each project is setup with git for Github storage, not handled by Android Studio, I only use git from the Linux devices via terminal.

My problem is that whenever I use Android Studio on the Windows 10 Tablet and return to one of my Linux devices, I get the following error when I try to use any git command.

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent
>   /media/Storage) Stopping at filesystem boundary
>   (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

I tried ones to run `git init`, but that put my entire history back to my `Initial Commit`.

Is there any way to get Android Studio to stop touching my .git directory, cause it is messing them up when working between Windows and Linux. Also if this happens again, how can I fix git without breaking my history?

Comment: Well I managed to fix the git history simply by doing a checkout, which did not even remove my unstaged changes. But I still need this to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is apparently simple. Just disable all plugins related to Version Control. No need to have Android Studio mess with git files when you use a terminal for that.